# Group numeric data into binned ranges

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

This is my original data:

```
    fi_diameter  ever_percent
0     -1.000000          0.00
1     -0.694212          0.00
2     -0.499782          0.00
3     -0.249749          0.00
4     -0.000000          0.00
5      0.249822          0.00
6      0.500218          0.00
7      0.749038          0.00
8      0.985645          0.00
9      1.251539          0.00
10     1.498179          0.00
11     2.122177          0.78
12     2.000000          3.70
13     2.251539          6.23
14     2.498179          8.66
15     2.746616         10.79
16     3.000000         12.13
17     3.251539         11.93
18     3.506353         10.78
19     3.756331          8.55
20     3.988504          5.90
21     4.237864          4.34
22     4.506353          2.89
23     5.011588          2.84
24     5.506353          1.88
25     5.965784          1.65
26     6.965784          2.49
27     7.965784          1.33
28     7.965784          3.13
```

I want to change my data to this type:

```
  1-2   4.48
  2-3  37.81
  3-4  37.16
  4-5   7.23
  5-6   6.37
  6-7   2.49
  7-8   4.46
```

I have try to use pandas of "groupby" ,but it not transform data to the like what i want it to be.

How do I get this output?

Comment: Mind doing `print(df.head(10))` and pasting the output in your question as text? It's not easy (possible) possible to copy data from a picture.

Comment: i have paste the data at the begin,but it garbled.i try it now

Comment: That's still a picture... I'm asking for text edited in your question.

Comment: I am sorry for that,I have changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Filter out values under 1
2. Use `pd.cut` and bin `fi_diameter`
3. Use the banned labels to groupby and sum on `ever_percent`

```
df = df.query('fi_diameter >= 1')
grouper = pd.cut(
    df['fi_diameter'], 
    bins=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 
    labels=['1-2', '2-3', '3-4', '4-5', '5-6', '6-7', '7-8']
)
df.groupby(grouper).ever_percent.sum().reset_index()

  fi_diameter  ever_percent
0         1-2          3.70
1         2-3         38.59
2         3-4         37.16
3         4-5          7.23
4         5-6          6.37
5         6-7          2.49
6         7-8          4.46
```

---

Here's how you generalise this for any upper bound.

```
mx = int(np.ceil(df['fi_diameter'].max()))
rn = np.arange(1, mx + 1)

df = df.query('fi_diameter >= 1')
grouper = pd.cut(
    df['fi_diameter'], 
    bins=rn, 
    labels=[
        str(i) + '-' + str(j) for i, j in zip(rn, rn[1:])
    ]
)    
df.groupby(grouper).ever_percent.sum().reset_index()

  fi_diameter  ever_percent
0         1-2          3.70
1         2-3         38.59
2         3-4         37.16
3         4-5          7.23
4         5-6          6.37
5         6-7          2.49
6         7-8          4.46
```

Comment: Thank you so much.I am sorry for that the terrible format bother you.

Comment: @Geologisted Sure, remember to mark accepted, and vote on the answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: Thank you from the bottom of my heart，I will check the rule later before next question.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be helpful?

```
bins = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]    
data['bins'] = pd.cut(data.fi_diameter, bins=bins, labels=['1-2', '2-3', '3-4', '4-5', '5-6', '6-7', '7-8'])    
df = data.groupby(['bins']).sum()    
df = df.drop('fi_diameter', axis=1)

df

    ever_percent
bins    
1-2     3.70
2-3     38.59
3-4     37.16
4-5     7.23
5-6     6.37
6-7     2.49
7-8     4.46
```

Comment: In know, this answer is shorter though. Might be helpful. updated the answer btw, labels added

Comment: I don't see how it's shorter or more helpful, it's just a polished copy of my answer.

Comment: you don't huh, ok. Your comment is very helpful though. No assumptions there.